# Problem in running r.sim.water

Tags: grass-gis, hydrology, simulation

I am trying to run the `r.sim.water` in GRASS. I have calculated the partial derivatives dx and dy rater map using `r.slope.aspect`. I am using this elevation map [1] to get the time-series depth map. But I got the output file is not being saved in the "outputDepth" rater map (says failed to open, on seeing the metadata).

```
r.sim.water -t elevin=testElevationLive@sampleMapSet dxin=dx@sampleMapSet dyin=dy@sampleMapSet rain_val=150 manin_val=0.015 depth=outputDepth nwalk=50000 outiter=20
```

STDOUT:

```
Min elevation   = 43.00 m
Max elevation   = 103.00 m
Mean Source Rate (rainf. excess or sediment)    = 0.000030 m/s or kg/m2s
Mean flow velocity  = 21.486384 m/s
Mean Mannings   = 0.015121
Number of iterations    = 647482826 cells
Time step   = 0.00 s
```

and on the cmd line:

```
Command 'd.rast map=outputDepth@sampleMapSet' failed
Details: Raster map <outputDepth@sampleMapSet> not found
```

Further I am not getting the time-series data output, by using the -t flag and setting the output_step to 20 as suggested here http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.sim.water.html.

[1] https://www.dropbox.com/s/ooxcj0y6v2kzeml/testElevationLive.tif?dl=0

Comment: Did setting the region (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149823/problem-in-running-r-slope-aspect-in-grass) help in any way?

Comment: Hi wenzeslaus, setting the region helped with getting the dx and dy slope raster from the elevation map, which is required in the r.sim.water function. I am just not able to figure out what's going wrong here.